# Apply children image width and height to container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this markup:

```
    <div class="img_container">
        <img src="file://localhost/img/a_bg.jpeg" alt="a_bg" />
    </div>
```

How can I apply the width and height of the image to the img_container?

**The image is on position absolute**

Comment: Have you tried `$div.width($img.width())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Markup:**

You will need to add an `id` to the image as below:

```
<div class="img_container">
        <img id="bgimg" src="file://localhost/img/a_bg.jpeg" alt="a_bg" />
    </div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
var img = $('#bgimg'); 

img.load(function(){
     //Get width of image
     var width = img.width();
     //Get height of image
     var height = img.height();
     $('.img_container').css("width", width);
     $('.img_container').css("height", height);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but I'd suggest:

```
$('.img_container img').each(function(){
    var w = this.naturalWidth,
        h = this.naturalHeight;
    $(this).parent().css({'height': h, 'width' : w});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<img src="file://localhost/img/a_bg.jpeg" alt="a_bg width="X" height="Y" />
```

And add this to you CSS

```
background-image: url(file://localhost/img/a_bg.jpeg);
background-size: Xpx Ypx;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```